# Controls.Find in TabPage inside TabPage

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have one TabControl2 inside TabControl1. TabControl2 is in all TabPages of TabControl1. In TabPage of TabControl2 is DataGridView and I need to work (Add.Rows etc) with this DataGridView. All is added programatically.

I am looking for the best way to find the right DataGridView so I would need something like :

```
DataGridView xxx = TabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls.Find("data_grid_view_name", false).FirstOrDefault() as DataGridView ***in TabControl1.SelectedTab***
Find this DataGridView by more :

Foreach (var y in TabControl1.Controls.OfType<Tabpage>())
{
//looks like a dirty code for me
}
```

Comment: The best way is to avoid losing it.  Add a variable to your class that stores the reference when you create the tab page.  Much the way the designer works.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

This Linq query returns the first `DataGridView` in your nested `TabControls`:

```
var gridViews = from tp in this.tabControl1.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>()
                from tc in tp.Controls.OfType<TabControl>()
                from tp2 in tc.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>()
                from grid in tp2.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>()
                select grid;
DataGridView firstGrid = gridViews.FirstOrDefault();
// if(firstGrid != null) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straight forward approach would be:

```
tabControl1.Controls.Find("data_grid_view_name", true);
```

Comment: And which DataGridView will be found when there is more of them in this control under same name?

Comment: @user2039470, is that really happening?

Comment: I can compile program with more controls of same name in TabControl2

Comment: So maybe easiest way to do it, is by if and else to give each datagridview unique name which actually solved my problem. Anyway, thanks for response.

Comment: @user2039470, yes that would be the best solution, and then just start the find from the `tabControl1` so that the `Find` is an easy one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
string dgvName = "data_grid_view_name";
if (tabControl1.SelectedTab != null)
{
    var nestedTabControl = (from TC in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<TabControl>() select TC).FirstOrDefault();
    if (nestedTabControl != null && nestedTabControl.SelectedTab != null)
    {
        Control[] matches = nestedTabControl.SelectedTab.Controls.Find(dgvName, true);
        if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is DataGridView)
        {
            DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)matches[0];
            // ... do something with "dgv" ...
        }
    }
}
```